# Spring MVC send a String from the client to controller using DOJO

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, dojo

I have the following Code on my Client

```
    var value = {"userId":form.userId.value};

var xhrArgs = {
    url : messageUrl,
    handleAs : "text",
    content: value,
    load : displayMessages,
    error : function(error) {
        dojo.byId("displayArea").innerHTML = "Error aquiring messages";
    }
};
dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
}
```

And on my server side controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getMessages.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String showMessageTable(@RequestParam("userId") String userId,ModelMap params)
{
```

I am getting a 400 error saying

The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()

Could someone explain what i'm doing wrong? I have tested the dojo code with firebug and the value seems to be passing just fine. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to check your Accept header, it should be `application/json`

Comment: @BijuKunjummen Do I have to do that even if im moving text? Isn't that for json objects?

Comment: Oh, okay did not realize that, you have annotated the response with @ResponseBody, Spring will then try and convert the response to json or xml based on the accept header. Just remove the @ResponseBody and it should then try to resolve the view(say a jsp) based on what you are returning from the `showMessageTable` method.

Comment: @BijuKunjummen Thanks for the reply! The ResponseBody annotation was something I just added for testing purposes. It doesn't give me the JSP page even if I didn't have it. So my code on the client side looks good? I am still getting the status 400 error. Also to note. when I put the url, the exact one that dojo is sending back in the address bar it takes me to a new page and displays data. So I know the MVC is working.

Comment: Just to confirm, with DOJO when you send a request, is it a normal POST or GET with the userId field a normal request parameter and NOT a json.

Comment: @user1636813 can you post the request you send to the client when executing that js code?

Comment: Typically the error you get is caused by missing request parameters. 

It seems like in your case the only way it can happen is when `form.userId.value` is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies! I figured it out. This code should work I had an error in my form where I was using a form to send a submit instead of using button's onClick event. It was sending two requests to spring instead of one. If anyone wants to know what the problem was I could post the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be helpful. visit to this **URL :** http://maxheapsize.com/2010/07/20/spring-3-mvc-ajax-and-jquery-magic-or-better-simplicity/